# Screen display not correct resolution after update nvidia-340.101

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 on my Dell M6400 with 17" lcd, resolution 1920x1200.

Before all, I use Ubuntu open-source driver (nouveau), but wanna the best performance with Fusion8 compositing, I try to install nvidia driver.

I've installed nvidia-340 (340.101) from PPA, not directly from Nvidia website.

After installation, I checked it in Additional Drivers and I see the list say "nvidia-340.101 from nvidia-340 (open-source).

But that's not my big problem. The problem is resolution, my screen have resolution 1920x1200 for the best, but now the 1920x1200 option display not correct, it's still 1920x1200 but it's wrong.

And now, everything seen bigger:
[image]

The resolution made me uncomfortable, it just like 1024x768, or worse.

But, this is not make sense.

I open Chrome browser, Chrome windows show anything big, just not right resolution and DPI.

But in Fusion8, anything show good, correct view.

I've tried to change resolution for bigger screen in xorg.conf; I change it to 2304x1440. Then, here is what I get:
[image]

The desktop show good, icon and anything smaller. In Chrome window, it show good but still blur on text and edge, not sharp as right resolution.

In Fusion8 workview, it's terrible, anything seen bigger.

Yah! I really to be mad. 
Something wrong? I need help to fix this. 
I think it's about driver or xorg.conf.